# How to plot a line graph filtering by two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, linegraph

this is my first time asking a question here so I'll try my best.

**CONTEXT/DATA:** I've a data set (example of it below) with daily data of different stores as well as their sales, forecast, region and store profile. Now I want to make a line plot showing the sales and forecast for each region/profile so it would be something like this for example 'South I-Big', 'South I-Medium' and 'South I-Small'.

Altogether I have 22 different regions and 3 store levels (small, medium and big).

| day | store | region | profile | sales | forecast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | 101 | South I | BIG | 12348.02 | 11987.00 |
| 2023-01-03 | 101 | South I | BIG | 13452.39 | 12546.00 |
| 2023-01-04 | 101 | South I | BIG | 14567.54 | 14385.00 |
| 2023-01-05 | 101 | South I | BIG | 17624.32 | 16292.00 |
| 2023-01-06 | 101 | South I | BIG | 18345.87 | 18109.00 |
| 2023-01-07 | 101 | South I | BIG | 20987.10 | 19786.00 |
| 2023-01-02 | 102 | South I | SMALL | 8456.98 | 8260.00 |
| 2023-01-03 | 102 | South I | SMALL | 9021.45 | 9110.00 |
| 2023-01-04 | 102 | South I | SMALL | 9237.89 | 9100.00 |
| 2023-01-05 | 102 | South I | SMALL | 9785.21 | 9277.00 |
| 2023-01-06 | 102 | South I | SMALL | 10325.33 | 9897.00 |
| 2023-01-07 | 102 | South I | SMALL | 10899.67 | 10345.00 |
| 2023-01-02 | 103 | South I | MEDIUM | 9865.32 | 9765.00 |
| 2023-01-03 | 103 | South I | MEDIUM | 10101.72 | 10010.00 |
| 2023-01-04 | 103 | South I | MEDIUM | 10672.43 | 10115.00 |
| 2023-01-05 | 103 | South I | MEDIUM | 11347.93 | 10872.00 |
| 2023-01-06 | 103 | South I | MEDIUM | 11785.20 | 11195.00 |
| 2023-01-07 | 103 | South I | MEDIUM | 12321.78 | 11942.00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to make a line plot "grouping" by region and then "grouping by" store profile while showing sales and forecast for each "combination" of it so I would have three separeted graphs for each region?!

I've tried to using 'for loop', 'dropdown menu' and other things that I found for similar questions here on Stack but since most of them were regarding just one grouping I couldn't work my way around it.

*Current output:* One graph for region showing the sales and forecast for all three profiles.
[Current output that I'm able to generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9XV2.png)

*Expected output:* One graph for each profile of store for each region, so for example for the region 'South I', I would have three plots (one for each profile: Small, Medium and Big) that show the sale and forecast of it.
[Expected output for each store profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avB7d.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the expected output? Do you expect to have three legends but six line charts for sales and forecasts? And are you aiming to represent 22 regions on one graph? With your current explanation, I would have to use subplots to deal with this.

Comment: @r-beginners, sorry for not making more clear before I edit the question to help on this point. I would want to expect three plots for each region and in each plot the sales/forecast data is shown.

No, I don't want to represent 22 regions in one graph because is a lot of info and the visualization gets messy. Before making the question here, I look up for some subplots materials but all of them only put one variable on the y-axis for each subplot. Do you have any reccomendation about subplots that I can try?!

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way for complex filtering in pnadas is `df.query()`. you can type your query in `str` and query that. for example:
`df.query("""region=='South I' and profile=='BIG'""")`

I don't know about the time complexity and efficiency of this method, but it works! Also, you can do this in multi-stages.

```
tmp_df = df[df['region']=='South I']
filt_df = tmp_df[tmp_df['profile']=='BIG']
```

But I think, the first method (`df.query()`) is easier. You can make a filter in lambda format:
`filter = lambda region, profile: df.query(f"""region=='{region}' and profile=='{profile}'""")`

Comment: Thank you for answering Amir, I'll try to see if this will help me build the plots =).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use animation (see below). Or creating multiple figures with a for loop, filtering the data using query (not shown below).

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
import plotly.express as px                        


txt = """
day store   region  profile sales   forecast
2023-01-02  101 South I BIG 12348.02    11987.00
2023-01-03  101 South I BIG 13452.39    12546.00
2023-01-04  101 South I BIG 14567.54    14385.00
2023-01-05  101 South I BIG 17624.32    16292.00
2023-01-06  101 South I BIG 18345.87    18109.00
2023-01-07  101 South I BIG 20987.10    19786.00
2023-01-02  102 South I SMALL   8456.98 8260.00
2023-01-03  102 South I SMALL   9021.45 9110.00
2023-01-04  102 South I SMALL   9237.89 9100.00
2023-01-05  102 South I SMALL   9785.21 9277.00
2023-01-06  102 South I SMALL   10325.33    9897.00
2023-01-07  102 South I SMALL   10899.67    10345.00
2023-01-02  103 South I MEDIUM  9865.32 9765.00
2023-01-03  103 South I MEDIUM  10101.72    10010.00
2023-01-04  103 South I MEDIUM  10672.43    10115.00
2023-01-05  103 South I MEDIUM  11347.93    10872.00
2023-01-06  103 South I MEDIUM  11785.20    11195.00
2023-01-07  103 South I MEDIUM  12321.78    11942.00
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt),sep='\t')
df

df2 = df.copy()
df2['region'] = 'North'
df2['sales'] = df2['sales']*1.1
df2['forecast'] = df2['forecast']/1.1
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2])
df3

fig = px.line(df3,
    x = 'day',
    y = ['sales','forecast'],
    facet_col = 'profile',
    facet_col_wrap = 1,
    title = '<b>Sales vs Forecast',
    render_mode = 'auto',
    animation_frame = 'region',
              range_y=[5000,25000]
              
                    )
fig.update_layout(template='plotly')
fig.layout.width=600

fig.update_yaxes(title={'text' : '$'})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @DougR, I'll definitely give a try!!